# sort word in alphabet order in C

Tags: c

Below code is for a test sample given in https://www.testdome.com/for-developers/solve-question/9621

The question is: 
Implement function sort_words that can sort an array of words which contain lowercase characters from english alphabet, in descending order.

For example, the array { "cherry", "orange", "apple" } should, after sorting, become { "orange", "cherry", "apple" }.

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_words(char *words[], int count)
{
    char *x;

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j<count; j++)
        {
            if ((char)(*words[i]) < (char)(*words[j]))
            {
                x = words[j];
                words[j] = words[i];
                words[i] = x;
            }
        }

    }
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    char *words[] = { "cherry", "orange", "apple" };

    sort_words(words, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
}
#endif
```

Result is correct, but the system notices the fail information "Performance test on a dictionary: Time limit exceeded"

Why this error happens and how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You only compare the first letters of the strings, which is enough for your minimal sample data, but isn't sufficient in general.  You wouldn't necessarily sort `apple`, `apricot`, `artichoke`, `alfafa` into the correct order.  Your sort uses a quadratic algorithm O(N^2) rather than O(N.logN).  That may be the trouble.  If there are 10,000 words in the dictionary, that's roughly the difference between 1E8 and 1.5E5 or a factor of about 125.

Comment: That you're hard casting those expressions to `char` is an indication you're not sure what `*words[i]` really *is*.

Comment: Use [qsort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) E.g `int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(char**)b, *(char**)a);
}
void sort_words(char *words[], int count)
{
    qsort(words, count, sizeof(*words), cmp);
}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY qsort() is good, and strcmp() can be used directly. No need for the cmp() function in this particular case.

Comment: @BjornA. It's *always* needed for any function that doesn't have exactly the `int ()(const void *, const void *)` signature. But I don't get what the funny casts are for, an implicit conversion of `a` and `b` to `const char *` should be enough...

Comment: @BjornA. Since `qsort`'s `compare` function receives `char **`, it can not be used directly. [Your proposal gets wrong results](http://ideone.com/amhPJD), Also [My proposal gets correct results](http://ideone.com/jUTkLY)

Comment: @FelixPalmen See my previos comment. [Your proposal gets wrong results](http://ideone.com/iD6BII)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: of course, the array elements are pointers, I overlooked that..

Comment: Guys, Please comment at least after reading the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code looks working, but it is actually wrong.

If the input set is:

`char *words[] = { "cherry", "orange", "apple", "oyster"};`

Then the output is:

```
orange oyster cherry apple
```

But the expected output is:

```
oyster orange cherry apple
```

The reason for that is in your sorting algorithm this condition:

`if ((char)(*words[i]) < (char)(*words[j]))`

Is basically just comparing the first letters of the two character arrays.

**NOTE**: This is not C++ and the data is not stored in `string` data type in C++. Where the `<` operator is overloaded to compare two strings.

Hence, instead of that line, you can use the `strcmp()`, like this:

```
if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) < 0)
```

Here is your working code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_words(char *words[], int count)
{
    char *x;

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j<count; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) < 0)
            {
                x = words[j];
                words[j] = words[i];
                words[i] = x;
            }
        }

    }
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    char *words[] = { "cherry", "orange", "apple", "oyester"};

    sort_words(words, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
#endif
```

Output:

```
oyester orange cherry apple
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the algorithm you are using is not efficient in terms of time complexity. The on eyou use is very trivial. It would no doubt sort the input, but would incur a lot of time when the input data set is huge. Try using some other sorting algorithm like - `mergesort, quicksort,` etc. These will do the same work in lesser time.
Refer how these algorithms work and try implementing them - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/sorting_algorithms.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use c standard library function qsort() to beat it....
My code as below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int compare_c_str(const void * str1, const void * str2)
{

    return strcmp(*(char **)str2,*(char **)str1);
}

void sort_words(char *words[], int count)
{
    // Waiting to be implemented
    qsort(words,count, sizeof(words[0]),compare_c_str);
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    char *words[] = { "cherry", "orange", "apple" };

    sort_words(words, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: it passed all tests.